# How to make extended app bar with tabs collapse and expand while scrolling?

Tags: java, android, material-design, toolbar, appbar

newbie here. I'm currently developing an app for our project at school and we wanted to show the logo on our extended app bar and will fade out and collapse upon scroll, so is there a way on how to do it?

Sample mockup I did to show what I meant about:
[canteen_home.gif](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/rrPZF20Wv4vujLXBCavNFYms1eu_j-1q8ImvUTr2UunvIdPhP_kwZB2EFPzBccsN_wb2lHhPUWs841isKO_MAa1-0K5e6uRWqy31IKoJOsQsBetaVh1nunkwp7-2YVsY0Pdp4LcxxNnD5N4zhhtizR2ATRvKjC3hnsQ9FOmUMO9oDN4aRRjRDcMcEGDQ2ImO4C-x9665HMoVzdTSqeJUfqFPk_c9pWZHfh-5IklUhf8RX5syEep4mBwxC-zRtuoLz4LtLfpBKCbnRTgVsrOHaYtcAwXyU0LaX8nYLl7ezq1tiOGQn2va1EDKnXaBYGaUB_dVtNObmVLIveWWSOmkYdy8U9YDjvuZdnUtFndjUsflohhe23Slvl3Ee8j7iIXAQV9BKhHpjmYKmgoELj4-rbpPzz3oa_jbRx6FWD394Fp96nePhth8Q8q3fr3BM07tfChJpgL9LMQUzvwmeDTVjxpx_-kwPI5oN0hmIDqooPE_yEe8JfSMBQR2TJ878NL8bXh9RFEM1Zh_oytnDFt1yLfmKbe0qO4a1W_hxe_fAbmu2ggI-FlQONrBJBNIpR0rs3OhRA=w360-h640-no)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got an answer to this, it was from Chris Banes' Cheesequare git highlighted by Paul:https://gist.github.com/iPaulPro/1468510f046cb10c51ea

And an edited version of mine:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Home">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/background"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="256dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            android:src="@drawable/hotdog"/>
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Coordinator behaviors are your friends :)

https://github.com/saulmm/CoordinatorBehaviorExample

https://medium.com/google-developers/intercepting-everything-with-coordinatorlayout-behaviors-8c6adc140c26#.5u1pplej6

Answer (score 1):

Refer [this](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/android-design-support-library-codelab/en).It explains exactly how to achieve what you want.